# Release iOS apps without needing the UDID

Tags: ios, node.js, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, udid

We are currently developing an iOS app, we want it to be installed on any device for testing, can we do so without needing the UDID for specific devices?

Comment: Use TestFlight.

Comment: Indeed, TestFlight is the way to go. You can use standard TestFlight builds, meaning all the testers need to have an account in App Store Connect. Or you can use external testers, in which case the builds first need to go through a (short) review from Apple. You only need the email address of your testers then though, or can even give them a link so they can enroll as testers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have three options:

Option one: Local installation. Physically connect the iOS device to your development mac and run it on that device in XCode. This will save it as an app on that device so you can test further even when it's disconnected. Main upside: simplicity. Main downside: the physical proximity required.

Option two: Testflight. This allows users to opt-in to a beta program where you can send out new builds to their devices. Main upside: allows a curated list of remote beta testers. Main downside: Builds are invalidated every 90 days.

Option three: Enterprise distribution. This allows you to package the app as a .ipa file and host it on a web server, where anyone with the link can download your app. Main upside: Widest possible reach and easiest download process for testers. Main downside: Costs $299 per year, you must be a corporation.

All three options have you dealing with Apple's often-confusing code-sign process. The first one can be done with automatic certificate management, but the other two will have to be manually configured.

Relevant setup tutorials:

[Testflight](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5352-testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing)

[Enterprise Distribution](https://medium.com/wso2-iot/how-to-export-in-house-developed-ios-app-as-an-enterprise-application-dc087bdd64c3)